# .NET6 - Add different headers depending on request route using middleware

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have an application that has both Razor Pages and API endpoints. The path of the API endpoints starts with "/api". I want to use middlware to add security headers & use a nonce for inline scripts. The nonce is not necessary for API endpints and the security headers are different depending upon what type of endpoint is requested.

I have tried a couple different things but am still having issues. With my first attempt (using the `.Map()` extension), the response header never seems to get set and the content that I am attempting to put into `HttpContext.Items` is not available at the Razor view. With my second approach (using `.Use()` and `if/else` logic), the response header gets set, but the item in HttpContext.Items isn't available.

### Attempt #1:

##### Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// logic to register services...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization()

## CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE ##
app.Map("/api", HandleApiRequests);
app.MapFallback(HandleRazorRequests);
## END CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE ##

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

With this, the response header and the HttpContext Item never seem to get set.

### Attempt #2:

##### Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// logic to register services...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization()

## CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE ##
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
    {
        HandleApiRequests(app);
    }
    else
    {
        HandleRazorRequests(app);
    }
});
## END CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE ##

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

With this, the response header is set, but the HttpContext Item isn't available when editing a razor view.

### Common between attempts

##### IApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs

```
public static void HandleRazorRequests(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSecurityHeaders(new SecurityHeaderOptions { IsApi = false });
}

public static void HandleApiRequests(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSecurityHeaders(new SecurityHeaderOptions { IsApi = true });
}

public static IApplicationBuilder UseSecurityHeaders(this IApplicationBuilder app, SecurityHeaderOptiosn options)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<SecurityHeaderMiddleware>(options);
}
```

##### SecurityHeaderMiddleware.cs

```
public class SecurityHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly SecurityHeaderOptions _options;

    public SecurityHeaderMiddleware (RequestDelegate next, SecurityHeaderOptions options)
    {
        this._next = next;
        this._options = options;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (this._options.IsApi)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = "my CSP for APIs";

            return await this._next(httpContext);
        }

        httpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = "my CSP for Razor Pages";

        // Add CSP Nonce to HttpContext Items dictionary so it can be used at the view-level.
        httpContext.Items["csp-nonce"] = "my nonce";

        await this._next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the desired result issue using `.UseWhen()`.

```cs
app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), _appBuilder =>
{
    // Apply middlware to manipulate context of requests
    // to endpoints whose paths starts with "/api".
});
app.UseWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), _appBuilder =>
{
    // Apply middlware to manipulate context of requests
    // to endpoints whose paths DO NOT start with "/api".
});
```

The problem with using `.Use()` is that that the request does not continue to the logic below the `.Use()` call. It branches the pipeline and never comes back. When you use `Use()` you need to complete the entire pipeline within the call; if it doesn't end in `.Run()`, it will never actually run the application.

When you use `.UseWhen()`, you branch off and add extra middleware for that request, but you come back and continue down the normal path.